# How to control a Windows application from Python

Tags: python, windows, ui-automation

I have the application installed on my windows PC, I want to launch that application using python and select dropdown options and do some other activities in that application.

I was able to launch the application using the `os.system` command, but I am not able to proceed further.

I want my program to do things like:
 * select from a dropdown menu
 * click on a button

How can my application control the user interface of another application?

Comment: No one can help you when you ask question like this, it can be 100 problems (bug in application, maybe you are doing something wrong, etc)

Comment: Hi Teemo, thanks for response,

Comment: just  wanted to know how to go ahead after launching the application, what modules, functions can be used to select drop down menu. I am new to python. I am using windows machine

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to *control* a Windows application from your code. In particular, you want your code to drive the *user interface* of a Windows application. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. You are right RJ

Comment: any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 15):

Normally, an application exposes a *user interface* (UI) for users, and an application programming interface (API) for programming.

- A **human being** uses **keyboard and mouse** to work with the **user interface** (UI)
- An **application** uses **programming** to work with the **application programming interface** (API)

The UI is designed for humans, and the API is designed for computers.

It is sometimes possible to use *programming* to control the *user interface* of another program -- so your program acts as if it were using the keyboard and mouse. This technique is often called "**UI automation**", and programs that do it are sometimes called "robots".

It's a big topic, and it can be quite complex. It's almost always better to use an API instead if you can: it's faster, simpler, more reliable.

If you do need to use UI automation, there are a few different tools that can help.

You are asking about Python, so here are a few UI automation tools that work with Python:

- **AutoIT** is a standalone product, but you can use Python to script it.
- **PyWinAuto** is designed for use from Python.
- **Sikuli** uses computer vision to find parts of the screen. I believe it comes with a recording tool as well.

Just to repeat: *UI automation is weird and hard*. If you can possibly use an API instead, your life will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks RJ for the response. WIll try API if i find any.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use pywinauto and when I am trying to launch application using app.start I am getting following error                                        Error opening DSP COF file 'C:\Users\general\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\t1.cof'!

Error Detail: The system cannot find the file specified.

Corrupt or incompatible installation, exiting...                                                                                                     can some one help me to resolve the issue

Comment: Start a new question, tag it "pywinauto" so that people who know pywinauto will see it. Explain how you installed Python, explain how you installed PyWinAuto, show your code, show how you run it, show the error, explain what you expect to happen. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to install pywinauto package
2. Try the following code to run the .exe file

   ```
   from pywinauto import application

   app =  application.Application()
   app.start("Notepad.exe")
   ```

Comment: No need to spell out the full path of notepad.exe?

Comment: @Egret in CMD if you only call `notepad` it will launch Notepad, no need for the full path

Answer (score -2):

here you are:
(with os ^_-)

```
import os
os.startfile('your exe file address')
```

Comment: This answer is obviously no use whatsoever as the questioner already indicated that they can launch their app, the part they are struggling with (which you don't even begin to address) is controlling the UI through automation