# Is it possible to access built in functions in an app using python

Tags: python

I am wondering if I can somehow make python for example **unpause** spotify song **through** spotify (without needing to click on gui elements). For example a button has a function in some app and I'm asking if I can somehow call that **function** through python.

And it doesn't necessarily need to be with python I just need to access a code **without** interacting with **GUI**. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let's see there's [How to control a Windows application from Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990545/how-to-control-a-windows-application-from-python) but...

Comment: Alternatively I guess you can fiddle with virtual screen or something [python, Windows 10: launching an application on a specific virtual desktop environment (work-spaces) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60879235/python-windows-10-launching-an-application-on-a-specific-virtual-desktop-envir)

Comment: See also [automation - Interact with other programs using Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288177/interact-with-other-programs-using-python). For Spotify in particular I don't know if it has an API, search for it. Otherwise I guess there's still the option of reverse engineer and hooking a debugger into it to control...